# How to implement a switch with text on it in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android

I want to make a switch with 2 states clearly shown on it like this
[image]

Instead of this
[image]

I've tried to write this in the XML file

```
   android:textOff="1"
   android:textOn="2"
```

And this on the Java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Switch simpleSwitch = findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch); // initiate Switch
    simpleSwitch.setTextOff("1");
    simpleSwitch.setTextOn("2");
}
}
```

But the result is always the latter with no text. Can someone guide me through this? It works with toggle buttons but the switch is more suitable for my UI.

Comment: maybe you can learn something from this library https://github.com/BelkaLab/Android-Toggle-Switch

Comment: This is the old style for switches. It is not recommended. You can still use `ToggleButton` which looks more like what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can enable text inside switch. I think you forgot to add this line

```
android:showText="true" or Switch.setShowText(boolean)
```

finally your code be like this,

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textOff="off"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOn="on" />
```

Thank you